# Suitable Company Wear

Tags: company-policy

Our company (IT and software development) requires us to wear a top with the company logo embroidered on it whenever we go to meet with clients. As of now, the options are polos, fleeces, and shell jackets (basically nothing but certain polos that are suitable for a woman to wear) but we can technically get the logo embroidered onto any clothing. Obviously, none of those are overly flattering options, but I'm not really sure what to propose to my boss to use. My first thought was blazers but that could be overly formal, I think?

My question is about what other companies use for logo wear for women.  If the options are literally just polos and blazers or if there's a less formal option that's flattering and still professional.

Comment: Why not wear a badge with the company logo instead? Also, this is not a fashion advice site, I'm afraid. Each culture/company/person may have different definitions for what is "flattering" and "professional".

Comment: What if it 80 °F.  You would look pretty silly and be uncomfortable in fleece or shell jacket.

Comment: Are you working for the Geek Squad? I can't imagine taking an IT consultant with a company logo on their outfit seriously, let alone hiring them.

Comment: @Lilienthal I work as an IT consultant and I wear company logo shirts and I am at what I consider a level up from the Greek Squad.

Comment: Perhaps the question can be reworded to "What is professional in appearance for females but also allows for branding?" Or perhaps you can convince your boss/superiors to have company merchandise for the employees to purchase which they find acceptable? (Puts the responsibility on management.) Honestly, as a woman, your options are not in abundance, perhaps a small sweater (or cardigan style sweater) is the best option. From my personal opinion, I find any company that makes their employees a walking billboard quite sad and will not do business with them.

Answer (score 3):

We use a vendor that offers the same styles cut for the specific shape and needs of common female alterations.  Generally business should reasonably try to offer equality in the male and female options.  If there is a style option for male members of your workforce women should be offered an option of similar value and function even if it takes a different form.  (A blouse, say, where men may be offered a 'style' button up in addition to the male/female version of the polos, for example).

Many current vendors offer a plethora of third party gear from major brands which they can then put your logo on and even advise you of which styles or offerings your art will work best on.

Here is one firm, for example, that firms I have worked for in the past have used:http://www.allstarlogo.com/mycompanystore/storeentry.asp

There are many options and which one is "right" or "best" can be driven by what types of gear your needs are in, and also who will work with you on pricing and product custom designs.

Answer (score 1):

A button-down shirt/blouse would work - with the company paying for them, of course.

I can see a use for company workwear for engineers etc who wouldn't want to be wearing a suit to crawl around a floor running cables, but if it's a business meeting, then any appropriate clothing would/should work. Badges are an option - it works for Realtors.